# Use $filter in controller for ng-repeat array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to apply a `$filter` to an array that populates `ng-repeat` from the controller. This array specifies the contents of "list" for `ng-repeat="l in list"`.

Can I do something like this?

```
var sidePanelFilter = $filter('sidePanel');

if (condition) {
    var numArray = myService.items;
    $scope.list = sidePanelFilter(numArray);
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="l in list | orderBy track by $index">
  {{ l }}
</li>
```

I want to specify the `$filter` in the controller so that I can generate `list` dynamically. I would not like to change the contents of the array.

**Edit**

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/YXeXLR) that reproduces my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to specify the $filter in controller"? Your example should work just perfectly

Comment: Is there a reason why you write $filter and not filter?

Comment: @hogan, to specify the Angular filter, as it appears when you inject it.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your filter as long as sidePanel is a registered filter. Could it be some logic within the filter?

Comment: See the above Codepen. It's behaving similarly.

Comment: ...a filter is used to filter an array, you're trying to use it to modify the items of the array. That's not what a filter does, it's supposed to *filter out* which items to return from the array. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter You're looking for `array.map` or somesuch

Comment: I've used filters inline in the html, e.g. `{{ item | filter }}` in the same capacity many times. The filter takes an `input` item as an argument, and can return items based on `if` `then` statements or just append html to an input. How can I do this in the controller?

Comment: @maurycy, see my attached codepen.

Comment: You want something like this (example using `array.map`) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVJVrz Feel free to break it out to a service or whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very useful function and fixed my problem. Supported ECMA Script 5.

Comment: I realized that it changes the contents of the list, I only want to filter the items, in the way that angular filters append html or replace items without modifying the original array.

Comment: Then don't modify the original array? Like I said, you can build for example a service that returns this value for you, based on the array from the scope. What you want in any case is not `filter` but something using `array.map` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our comments, you want to *change* the items of the array, not return a subset of the array. So what you want isn't a `filter` but a method like `array.map`.

```
numArray = numArray.map(function(i) {
    return i + " yards";
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVJVrz

Comment: I actually don't want to change the items of the array. I just realized that was a side-effect of `array.prototype.map`. I only want to `filter` them.

Comment: This may have occured to you but the absolutely easiest solution is not touching the array at all http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wayaZK or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVJVbY

Comment: Well received, but I want to generate the `li` completely dynamically, without including characters in HTML.

Comment: Did you see the second example?

Comment: I just looked at it. I supposed I could add both prefix and suffix items arount the `{{ l }}`, but I have 4 different `lists`, and those prefixes and suffixes would only need to apply to 1 of them, so I would have to set their values to `null` for the other 3. This is doable but doesn't seem like the most natural fit for the problem.

Comment: [This still remaps the array, changing the value of the array's contents](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/gpvpNO) . I want to be able to retain the array contents in the scope and pass them through on an `ng-click` event.

Comment: This still applies the service to all of the list items, I only want to apply the filter to one of the 1/4 potential `$scope.lists`.

Comment: Your original problem is solved so you should set this as answered, ask a new one and include all your requirements from the start (but try to solve it yourself first).